# robot localization initial position

Tags: navigation, gps, robot-localization, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using robot localization to fuse odomtery, imu, and rtk gps data. Since the gps data is rtk its published a relative distace to a nearby base station, meaning I don't need to use the navsat transform node. My gps base station is the origin of my map frame and my robot usually initializes around x = -180 y = -80.

I'm finding that when I initialize, the initial position is set to (0,0) and it takes the kalman filter around 40 seconds to drift over to (-180,-80) where the robot actually is. I logged my gps data in a bag file to make sure that it wasn't publishing (0,0) initially, which its not.

How do I tell robot_localization what my actual initial position is? I had the thought that I could increase the covariance on my initial position, here is what it is  currently:

```
<rosparam param="initial_estimate_covariance">[1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9 ,0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9 ,0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9 ,0,    0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,
                                               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9]</rosparam>
```

But that would be a waste of valuable knowledge. I start the robot in the same place each time. I'd like to have a very small covariances to represent that and then set the initial position somehow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268505/robot-localization-initial-position/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2017-08-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-10**:
What version of ROS are you using?

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-08-10**:
ROS Indigo

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-08-10**:
Oh, now I see that there is an initial_state parameter in the [new documentation](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html).  Does that work on ROS Indigo?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-10**:
[It would appear so](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#initial-state). To find it, I just changed "lunar" to "indigo" in the URL. You should write this up as your answer and accept it.

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-08-10**:
I'll test it out to see if it works and then post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On June 12th 2017 the parameter initial_state was added to robot_localization [[1]](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/CHANGELOG.htm)

Currently the change has been made to the following versions of ROS: Indigo / Kinetic / Lunar [[2]](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/lunar-devel/src/ros_filter.cpp)

If you haven't done so since June 12th 2017 you will need to update the package using:

```
sudo apt-get intstall ros-<your version>-robot-localization
```

Then this will work

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2017-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1